# Capsicum ( Peppers ) leaves have holes, turned yellow, curled no bugs visible

Tags: leaves, pests, peppers, pest-damage

Capsicum ( Melbourne, Australia ), outdoor on balcony in a pot, started to have holes on leaves, turned yellow, curled, but no bugs visible. Has proper drainage, watered around every 2-3 days (may water too much?), around 4 hrs direct sunlight from my spot per day.

I have other Capsicum sowed around same time but don't have the same symptoms? What's going on :( ??

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check ph, should be between 6.0-6.8. Clay or sand-like soil? Might have nutrition lock out. Cant use vital nutrients if ph is not in range to absorb minerals needed for optimum photosynthesis. Once your good on that part calcium and iron should be more available for absorption. Sometimes its not about what it needs, but what it doesn’t need, like salts from municipal water sources...

Comment: Sorry no one’s had any answers for u